# How to stop converting “greater than” and “less than” symbols to entities in Rich Text Editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, jodit

I would like to know how to disable the conversion for symbols `<` and `>` in view source to `&lt;` and `&gt;`
I am using Jodit Editor React, https://github.com/jodit/jodit-react.
any suggestions, how to disable specific conversions.

```
<#list items as itm>

changes to

&lt;#list items as itm&gt;
```

Comment: And why would you like to stop converting them?

Comment: @gazdagergo thanks for reply, its user scenario, and is it possible to do so??

Comment: I'm just asking as I do not see why does this matter how the html code looks like. As the user sees `<` in the WYSIWYG, the final page is being rendered with `<`. And the reason of the conversion is not conflict with html tags like `<p>` etc.